# Need convert this code to VB NET

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I am using javascript and wanted to convert into VB.NET.
The code is all about check weather parentheses balance or not in given string.

```
var ncount = 1
var str = "hello(world)"

if (ncount != 0) {
ncount = ncount - 1
//Using for loop to search each char in string
for (???) {
if (//If open parentheses is found)
    ncount++;
else if (//If close parentheses is found)
    ncount--;
else
    //parentheses not balance
}

}else {
// Parentheses balanced
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  Loops (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx) and conditionals (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) are pretty standard structures.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Dim bracketsBalanced = AreBracketsBalanced("hello(world)") ' True

Public Shared Function AreBracketsBalanced(input As String) As Boolean
    Const LeftParenthesis As Char = "("c
    Const RightParenthesis As Char = ")"c
    Dim BracketCount As Int32 = 0

    For Index As Int32 = 0 To input.Length - 1
        Select Case input(Index)
            Case LeftParenthesis
                BracketCount += 1
            Case RightParenthesis
                BracketCount -= 1
        End Select
    Next
    Return BracketCount = 0
End Function
```